# Access instance variable with route namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Routes.rb**

```
  resources :academies do
    resources :posts
  end
```

**Url:** /academies/1/posts

```
<%=link_to edit_academy_path(@academy) do %>
   <i class="fa fa-university"></i> <span>My academy</span>
<% end %>
```

but I get this error

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"academies", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

because it doesn't exist **@academy**.

How could I access to @academy in every sub routes of /academies/1/*resourse ?

Comment: Do you have `@academy` in your `edit` action of `academies` controller?

Comment: yes, I do. It's been created by standard crud rules

Answer (score 2):

You should simply set it in every action of `posts_controller` using `before_filter`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_academy
  # ...
  private
  def find_academy
    @academy = Academy.find(params[:academy_id])
  end
end
```